# Book where there was only one race

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a story once where we had all interbred such that there were no longer any blacks, whites, Asians, etc.  We were all 'brown'.  Somehow they 'found' 5 children that were purebred 'races', and I don't remember much else.

Comment: Did the book specifically run in that direction of plot? Because I know of one where a boy realizes late in the narrative that he is one of the purebred, being kept for breeding. It had an early scene where he scratches his friends arm and realizes it's brown beneath the fake skin.

Comment: That does sound familiar now that you mention it - like the kids were being brought up in the Truman Show where 'brown people' had their skin colored so the 'purebreds' didn't feel like outcasts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that this may be Piers Anthony's *[Race Against Time](http://books.google.com/books/about/Race_Against_Time.html?id=riEPAAAACAAJ)* as per my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86807/ya-novel-where-the-main-characters-family-have-been-replaced-by-impostors).

I'll just quote the text of it:

> It involves a 20th century white boy accidentally scratching off the skin of his friend, showing that it's all brown underneath, and that there's some vast conspiracy that everyone but him is involved in. I want to say that his friend still helps him, but the majority of it is him corresponding with a penpal through coded letters (they do something like having the message be in every third letter) to escape and find more people like him.
>
> Of course, the reveal isn't that the people around him aren't human, but that

[Spoiler ahead]

> The human race has become a homogenous brown due to the mixing of races here in the 24th century, and the protagonist, his pen pal, and a few others are genetic throwbacks to earlier races being preserved in a zoolike "natural environment".

Comment: I think that's it.  I got into him after reading his "Incarnations of Immortality" series so I probably was sampling others he had written.  Thanks!